Read a kafka message and load data into xml file
Hello datastage developpers,
I need your help please,
I have a datastage job where we use a kafka connector to read the message from kafka and a transformer stage in order to format the message to json format adding  brackets and at the end a sequentiel file to load data into json file
I want to update this job to read the messages from kafka and load it into xml file
how can we do it in the same job ?
